# I have alias and keystore password and its file but forgot key password

Tags: android

I have forgotten my key password (not my keystore password I have it)
I have jks file,I remember alias and keystore password 
every questions and topics are about recover keystore password not key password
I have tried log.idea , task history etc... is there anyway to find it?

when I want create new key android studio display this error "Password verification failed
"

Comment: You should try https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute forcing tool that may be of use: http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/

Comment: I used it but i think it just find kestore password not key password.